# WagtailCMS Multisite Site Configuration

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, wagtail

I am building a non profit association website and am using the `Sites` feature to build custom templates for their chapter sites. What I am trying to do is re-use the templates by targeting the Sites name or id or...  For instance, if you look at the screenshot below, I have two sites so far I am testing and I have a model called `StandardPage(Page)` and a matching template `standard_page.html`.  The main site will look slightly different than the chapter sites, but I would like to re-use the `standard_page.html` template for both with an `if` path is this, display this, if not this...

I know this isn't correct, but to illustrate what I am trying to do:

**standard_page.html**

```
{% if request.path != '/' %}
  {% include 'includes/chapter/_chapter-standard-page-content.html' %}
{% else %}
  {% include 'includes/ao/_ao-standard-page-content.html' %}
{% endif %}
```

[image]

They have over 50 chapters around the world, so you can see how important it would be to be able to re-use templates so I am not having to created each template for each model for each chapter .

Thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure what it is you're asking.  It's perfectly valid to reuse templates between sites.  You might have a look at Page [get_template](https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/blob/stable/1.8.x/wagtail/wagtailcore/models.py#L764) or the django [extends](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/templates/builtins/#std:templatetag-extends) feature.

Comment: The `wagtail.contrib.settings` module is probably the best way to attach different parameters (such as page styles) to different sites: http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v1.8/reference/contrib/settings.html

Comment: So I feel dumb now because I can't figure this out :)  @moritz I have each one of my template pages above extending from a custom template.  The thing I am trying to figure out is how do I use the `ao-standard...` template by default and show the `chapter-standard...` template if the host name is preceded with a sub domain.

Comment: @moritz Love the `get_template` feature!!  Added `chapter = models.BooleanField(default=None)` to my model for the checkbox and then `def get_template(self, request): if self.chapter: return 'includes/chapter/_chapter-standard-page-content.html' return 'includes/ao/_ao-standard-page-content.html'` to choose template.

Comment: @StudioRooster Great, I'm glad you found a solution.  Do have look at ``wagtail.contrib.settings`` like @gasman suggested.  I do find those invaluable when working with multisite configurations.

Comment: Will do. If you can change your original comment to an answer, I can mark it  for you.  Thanks again.